# Copy/concatenate dynamically allocated C style strings

Tags: c++, string, dynamic, concatenation

I am trying to write a function to concatenate two dynamically allocated C-style strings. Am I correct in my design that you first would have to copy the destination to a temp `char[]`, delete the original memory allocation, get the length of the two `char[]`, allocate new memory with that new length then copy the chars to the `dest[]`?

So pseudo code:

```
void concat(char* dest, char *source)
{
    char temp = dest;

    delete [] dest;

    char dest = new char [new size];

    copy temp to dest;

    copy source to dest;
}
```

Am I fundamentally misunderstanding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't delete `dest` as it could be pointing to non-dynamic memory. Then use `strcat` or, much safer, `strncat`.

Comment: I am having to write my own concat function though that will be passed two dynamically allocated cstyle strings.

Comment: In that case, I'd leave `dest` alone and allocate an entirely new array and return a pointer to that. There is a potential for memory leaks, but that's probalby not a concern in this case. The size is pretty easy to figure, strlen(dest) + strlen(source) + 1. Then you'll want to append the strings instead of copying them. But overall, you've got the right idea.

Comment: Using `strncat()` correctly is surprisingly hard.  Quickly: what's does the length parameter contain?  If you can't answer straight off, it isn't safe to use it.  (Hint: it is not `sizeof(dest)`!)

Answer (score 0):

You must copy to a temporary buffer if the source and destination overlap, but not if they don’t.  With C `char*`, this could happen, and you might get `mycat(str+2, str)` as a test case.

Answer (score 0):

Your *concat() prototype* is:

```
void concat(char* dest, char *source);
```

So, new allocation of "dest" inside the concat() function will not get reflected at the caller function.

Two possible solutions:

1. Caller function should re-allocate "dest" with new length and then, pass to concat(). In this case, concat() does not perform re-allocation.
2. If concat() is allowed to perform re-allocation, then, it's prototype should be changed to:

   a) `void concat(char** dest, char *source);`  -> strcat/strncat can be used in this case as suggested by Jonathan Leffler

   b) `char* concat(char* dest, char *source);`  -> need to return the new allocated "dest" in this case